# Queue-based load leveling pattern API Gateway to Step Functions

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs, aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge

I want to implement a queue-based load leveling pattern between API Gateway and Step Functions. I need advice on weighing different options, as this will be the first time I am implementing this:

Option 1:

Have API Gateway enqueue messages into an SQS queue and have a mechanism to trigger step functions when messages are added to the queue.

The challenges with this option:

- It is not clear how to have the step functions triggered when messages are added to the queue. I cannot use Eventbridge pipes since they are not available in China.
- Controlling the number of executions to perform is not clear, in case of large scale loads.

Option 2:

Have API Gateway push the events to an Eventbridge bus and create a rule to trigger step functions when an event is received. This approach seems more implementable since the Eventbridge rules can easily trigger step functions.

Challenges:

- Can the Eventbridge bus persist many events long enough just as SQS can?
- Consuming events in the order they were added to the bus will be a nice add-on if this is possible.

Any advice and insights on which option can be preferable over the other based on implementation and avoiding the accidental loss of messages received for API Gateway?

Comment: Can you please clarify the question a bit? What are you trying to achieve? The API Gateway already scales automatically for you. So you could just trigger a Express Step Functions without SQS or EventBridge in the middle?

Comment: I want to allow the throttling of messages between API Gateway and the step functions. The system should persist messages after after failures for retries. Now the question becomes: whether API Gateway can persist failed messages/events and retry them.